# I need to automatically repeat after a certain line. selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to automatically repeat after a certain line. example; There is a 200 line code and it will repeat 20 times after line 60

and other question;
After a certain period of time, it should automatically turn itself off and start over. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with repeat? Repeat the entire code?
To repeat a code part, do as following:

```py
for x in range(0, 5):
     <code>
     <code>
```

Comment: I want the code to repeat after a certain part

Comment: Use a for loop. `for x in range(0, 5): <code>`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not very experienced in programming. For the first question you will have to work with a [loop](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops) . To run a loop a specific number of times python has the [range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) function that will help you.

The second question is different, because it has many possible answers. You migt have a look at schedulers, but before that maybe see why you would really need it in the first place. Sometimes there are easier ways to come to a similar solution!

Comment: yeap. i am new to this stuff.  I wrote to find an appointment on a visa site, first of all, I log in to the site and progress, and on the last page, the closest appointment date is written and the program sends me this date by e-mail.  I'm copying the actions on the last page and pasting hundreds of them one after the other, so I need a shortcut.  Secondly, since this page logs out of my account after 2 hours, my aim is to close this program automatically after 1 hour and open it again.